# Change 'post_modify' with a query

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to change the value of `post_modified` columns with a query like that:

```
$wpdb->query( "UPDATE `$wpdb->posts` SET `post_modified` = ".$data_modifica_post."  WHERE ID = ".$iddelpostdaverificare."");
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to change manually `post_modified` (and `post_modified_gmt`) or it only change automatically with an update of the post from the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Marin Atanasov and @hobo to help me to solve my problem on stackoverflow. If you are interested you can check the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588615/how-can-i-change-post-modify-with-a-query/25590395#25590395)

The problem was in the way i wrote the query, because it needs quotes around the date (eg = `'".$data_modifica_post."'`).